# Space press change event

Tags: javascript

I would like to press the spacebar to cause the first event. Once that event happens, I would like to press the spacebar again and cause the second event to happen... repeat. -- like play/pause controls in video BUT NOT VIDEO ---  I want to this to html id= events!!!

For example: the following codes works fine to 'click' the event 'play' using <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, and 'pause' using (<kbd>P</kbd>). but I want to 'pause' using <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> as well.

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
    play.click();
}
if (evt.keyCode == 80) {
    pause.click();
};
```

Comment: So toggle a variable that has the state.

Answer (score 1):

```
var playing = false;
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
    if (playing) { pause.click(); }
    else { play.click(); } 
    playing = !playing;
}

if (evt.keyCode == 80) {
    pause.click();
};
```

Comment: awsome..! working now..! add closing bracket. change var playing to true so fires play on first click.